# How to supply value to an annotation dynamically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I have created a cutom annotation with a `boolean` value attribute.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
    boolean value() default false;
}
```

The annotation should be set dynamically based on property read from a configuration file.

I've tried to inject the value directly from the configuration:

```
@CustomAnnotation("${xxxxx.xxxxx.enableFeature:false}")
public void apply(){}
```

And:

```
@CustomAnnotation(""#{new Boolean('${xxxxx.xxxxx.enableFeature:false}")
public void apply(){}
```

I'm getting the same compilation problem for both solutions:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean

---

I've tried a third solution by injecting the value as variable and then using it:

```
@Component
public class ApplyClass {

@Value("${xxxxx.xxxxx.enableFeature:false}")
private boolean enableFeature;

@CustomAnnotation(enableFeature)
public void apply(){}

}
```

I've got another compilation issue:

> The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression

---

Even by switching the variable to constant, this is not working.

```
@Component
public class ApplyClass {

@Value("${xxxxx.xxxxx.enableFeature:false}")
private static final boolean enableFeature; // ---> Leads to compilation problem 

@CustomAnnotation(enableFeature")
public void apply(){}

}
```

---

So, a part from doing code smells like:

```
@Component
public class ApplyClass {

@Value("${xxxxx.xxxxx.enableFeature:false}")
private  boolean enableFeature; 

private static final ENABLE_FEATURE_CONSTANT = enableFeature

@CustomAnnotation(ENABLE_FEATURE_CONSTANT)
public void apply(){}

}
```

1. Is that a known limitation of `annotations` ?
2. Is there any recommendation or solution a part from using `Strings`
   instead of other types ?

Comment: The value of an annotation element cannot be dynamic. So the answer to your first question is: Yes, that's a known limitation. Any sort of dynamic behavior you see with annotations comes from the code which processes the annotations at runtime.

Comment: @Slaw, Yes, totally agree in case of a type different  from String. 
By moving the value to String, We can achieve dynamic behaviour since the property becomes injectable inside the annotation value.

Comment: But there is still a distinction. The _value of the annotation element_ is still a constant. It's the _code which processes the annotation_ that reads the value of the element and does something with it. In other words, Spring Boot has some code somewhere that does something like `element.getAnnotation(Value.class).value()` and _interprets_ the `String` as something that needs to resolve to a value from another place (e.g. a properties file); it then queries the appropriate place, resolves the value, and does something with said value (depending on what the annotation means in that context).

Comment: @Slaw Fair enough. Thanks

Comment: Actually you can place "${property.name}" into annotation property values and it works (at least in SpringBoot 2.5). but concerning boolean properties i see developer of annotation has to provide booleanStr alternative property or java needs upgrade of syntax.