# Using application property in Spring Boot annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, jackson, date-format

I have the following date field in my DTO class:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy")
private LocalDateTime date;
```

I define the date format in my application.yml as shown below:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    date-format: "dd.MM.yyyy"
```

I am trying to use this format in my DTO field directly like below:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="${spring.jackson.date-format}")
private LocalDateTime date;
```

Is it possible? Or do ı have to add a `@Value` field like below? I tried but cannot use this `dateFormat` in my date field.

```
@Value("${spring.jackson.date-format}")
private String dateFormat;
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65103102/set-external-date-format-pattern-to-jsonformat-from-a-properties-file

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but when faced with questions like this one, I tend to try it both ways, and see which one works.  A lot of software development consists of trying something, testing it out, failing, then trying something else.

Comment: TL;DR: Java annotation do not accept variable values. More detailed - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10636201/2886891, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62798011/2886891, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54403433/2886891, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14268981/2886891, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12568385/2886891

Comment: @Unmitigated Thanks for help, it seems to suggest to use Value as I tried, but it is also not working.

Comment: @HonzaZidek So, do you have any suggestion for using date format in DTO? Should I use Value annotation or anything? I also tried to use it but could not make it work.

Comment: The way to achieve your goal would be probably something like modifying the JSON serializer/deserializer, which *can* be done in the code, so dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have good tips here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates

Either configure the default format, like

```
spring.jackson.date-format=dd.MM.yyyy
```

or configure the serializer:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyJsonConfig {
    @Value("${spring.jackson.date-format}")
    private String dateFormat;

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.simpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat);
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)));
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)));
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it says "Although setting the default format like this is quite handy and straightforward, there's a drawback to this approach. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the Java 8 date types, such as LocalDate and LocalDateTime. We can only use it to format fields of the type java.util.Date or the java.util.Calendar." I use `LocalDateTime`, then should I configure serializer?

Answer (score 2):

1. **JsonFormat** is not a spring annotation, therefore you can't use spring expression language.
2. **spring.jackson.date-format** defines default date format for some types of date classes, you don't have to use this variable inside **JsonFormat**, just define the value. For details see e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates
3. If you would like to be more flexible in spring you can define converters for any type, see the same article.